# How to fix "Error opening block StreamChunkId" on external spark shuffle service

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to run spark jobs from my zeppelin deployment in a kubernetes cluster. I have a spark shuffle service (daemonset - v2.2.0-k8s) running on a different namespace as well. Here are my spark configs (set on zeppelin pod)

```
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.docker.image=<spark-executor> 
--conf spark.executor.cores=5
--conf spark.driver.memory=5g
--conf spark.executor.memory=5g
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=<svc-account> 
--conf spark.local.dir=/tmp/spark-local 
--conf spark.executor.instances=5 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true 
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true 
--conf spark.kubernetes.shuffle.labels="app=spark-shuffle,spark-version=2.2.0" 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=5   
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1 
--conf spark.kubernetes.shuffle.namespace=<namespace> 
--conf spark.kubernetes.docker.image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent 
--conf spark.kubernetes.initcontainer.docker.image=kubespark/spark-init:v2.2.0-kubernetes-0.5.0 
--conf spark.kubernetes.resourceStagingServer.uri=<ip:port>
```

But I get the following logs from external spark-shuffle and spark executors spawned by zeppelin:

```
+ /sbin/tini -s -- /opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.KubernetesExternalShuffleService 1
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/spark/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/sl
f4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/spark/jars/kubernetes-client-3.0.1.jar!/org
/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2020-01-14 03:37:31 INFO  ExternalShuffleService:2574 - Started daemon with proces
s name: 10@unawa2-shuffle-unawa2-spark-shuffle-d5cfg
2020-01-14 03:37:31 INFO  SignalUtils:54 - Registered signal handler for TERM
2020-01-14 03:37:31 INFO  SignalUtils:54 - Registered signal handler for HUP
2020-01-14 03:37:31 INFO  SignalUtils:54 - Registered signal handler for INT
2020-01-14 03:37:31 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2020-01-14 03:37:31 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: root
2020-01-14 03:37:31 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: root
2020-01-14 03:37:31 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to:
2020-01-14 03:37:31 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to:
2020-01-14 03:37:31 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2020-01-14 03:37:32 INFO  KubernetesExternalShuffleService:54 - Starting shuffle service on port 7337 (auth enabled = false)
2020-01-14 03:38:35 INFO  KubernetesShuffleBlockHandler:54 - Received registration request from app spark-application-1578973110574 (remote address /192.168.2.37:40318).
2020-01-14 03:38:36 INFO  ExternalShuffleBlockResolver:135 - Registered executor AppExecId{appId=spark-application-1578973110574, execId=5} with ExecutorShuffleInfo{localDirs=[/tmp/spark-local/blockmgr-8a26a714-3ecb-46dd-8499-ff796fa97744], subDirsPerLocalDir=64, shuffleManager=org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleManager}
2020-01-14 03:39:15 ERROR TransportRequestHandler:127 - Error opening block StreamChunkId{streamId=527834012000, chunkIndex=0} for request from /192.168.3.130:50896
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to open file: /tmp/spark-local/blockmgr-8a26a714-3ecb-46dd-8499-ff796fa97744/0f/shuffle_1_0_0.index
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.getSortBasedShuffleBlockData(ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.java:249)
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.getBlockData(ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.java:174)
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockHandler$1.next(ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.java:105)
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockHandler$1.next(ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.OneForOneStreamManager.getChunk(OneForOneStreamManager.java:89)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processFetchRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:103)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
.
.
.
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/spark-local/blockmgr-8a26a714-3ecb-46dd-8499-ff796fa97744/0f/shuffle_1_0_0.index (No such file or directory)
        at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:306)
        at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:293)
        at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
        at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

[EDIT]

I mounted the local dir /tmp/spark-local into my pods. When I `ssh` into each node, I confirmed that the block manager exists in one of the worker nodes (I'm guessing this is the expected behavior). The error occurs when one of the shuffle pods from another worker node tries to access the same block manager.

Comment: Hi, to start with check the images you use and try to remove `--conf spark.local.dir=/tmp/spark-local`. Also to be sure that your images are correct and support the functionality you expect try the simple example, eg.: https://apache-spark-on-k8s.github.io/userdocs/running-on-kubernetes.html#dynamic-executor-scaling . After that include additional options for your case.

Comment: Hi @AliaksandrSasnouskikh, thank you for the reply. I'm using the same spark images to run spark jobs on other deployments. They work well and I think it's because they're not using spark shuffle service. I can also see the blocks being created on other nodes (I mounted /tmp/spark-local). I'll edit the post to provide more details.

Comment: I do not understand why do you mount `spark.local.dir`, since you're are using external shuffle service all the actions related to the shuffle files should go through it rather than through local dirs.

Comment: Based on the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), ```spark.loca.dir - This should be on a fast, local disk in your system.```. I needed to mount the directory so my shuffle pods can write to each node's local disk.

Comment: I tried removing `spark.local.dir` in my spark-submit configs but the results were the same.

Comment: Please run the example https://apache-spark-on-k8s.github.io/userdocs/running-on-kubernetes.html#dynamic-executor-scaling with your images and with the `kubespark` ones. Just to be sure that it is not related to your images. If your images are built from the Spark release branch, it'll not work for you since the external shuffle service support is not yet released: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#future-work .

Comment: Hi @AliaksandrSasnouskikh, apologies for the late reply, I had to redirect my efforts to other projects I've been working on. Anyway, I did your last suggestion and I was able to run the example with dynamicAllocation enabled. I might need to re-build the images we're using for spark-driver & executor. Also, I kept `spark.local.dir config` in the spark job and it worked. I'll get back to you once I'm able to give updates. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Hi @AliaksandrSasnouskikh I just have another question. I used the official images from `kubespark` but it still shows the same error for about 20% of the time. I'm using spark-2.2.0-k8s. I just want to confirm that despite the docs saying it supports dynamicAllocation, it's not yet stable? (sorry for reiterating your comment). I've also seen the following JIRA tickets [SPARK-24432](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24432) and [SPARK-25299](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25299). But it says it only affects version 3.0.0. Thanks in advance for the clarification:)

Comment: Basically `2.2.0-k8s` is experimental brach used for the POC of Spark on K8s, seems that it is no longer supported. The preferable would be to wait for 3.0.0 release, which should already be soon.

Comment: Thanks @AliaksandrSasnouskikh , I don't know the standards of how we should proceed here but can you answer the question so I can have it marked as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summary out of the comments thread.

In order to run Spark on Kubernetes with dynamic allocation enabled you can:

#### Follow the [apache-spark-on-k8s guide](https://apache-spark-on-k8s.github.io/userdocs/running-on-kubernetes.html#dynamic-executor-scaling)

Important notes:

- You should base your images on [kubespark](https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/spark/tree/branch-2.2-kubernetes/resource-managers/kubernetes/docker-minimal-bundle/src/main/docker) images, which are built with the forked [Apache Spark 2.2.0](https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/spark/tree/branch-2.2-kubernetes/)
- The feature is experimental and out of the support

#### Wait until Spark 3.0.0 is released with [SPARK-24432](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24432) and [SPARK-25299](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25299)